# Kentico - Using the calendar to filter booking system events

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Having a lot of problems getting to grips with the Kentico CMS, but I'm finally getting somewhere close. I'm using a normal portal engine and running Kentico 5.5 RC2 on a local installation.

I currently have an events page which uses a repeater to display all of the events that are available on the system currently. I want to use a calendar to be able to filter the events in that repeater. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways.

- Custom user control
- Custom web part
- Query string parameters

The easiest would be the last one. Or a combination of the first two with the last one. Add your calendar control via your preferred method (an AJAX Calendar, jQuery calendar, <asp:Calendar>, or whatever you like) and have it populate in a text field. Then have that run some JavaScript to change the URL query string which will reload the page.

Go to your Kentico repeater's web part properties. In the `Content filter->WHERE condition` field, you can write a standard SQL WHERE clause and inject query string parameters via the special macro: `{?QUERYSTRINGPARAMETERNAME?}`. For example http://url/page?myfilter=2 would be `{?myfilter?}`. That would make the `WHERE` clause something like: `{?myfilter?} = '' OR {?myfilter?} = SqlFieldToCompare`.

Kentico claims they escape that macro for security, though I haven't personally confirmed that. Works for us though.

If you went with a customer user control or web part, you could use safer postback methods with a Control macro (instead of the above QueryString macro).

For more info on macros, see the [Developer's Guide Appendix A Macros](http://www.kentico.com/docs/devguide/appendix_a___macro_expressions.htm).

Comment: Awesome, that answers a lot. Just one minor problem though for me, I don't know how to add vanilla asp.net to a page at all. Could you point me in the right direction to figure out how to add things like textboxes or buttons please? Also how to do codebehind on a single page? (e.g. if I use <asp:Calendar> above, I'll need to hit the C# code to say textbox1.Text = calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() etc.) I think with that, I'll be able to move on a lot further with Kentico. Without being able to manipulate the .net code and codebehind things are really hard!

Comment: Actually, I've now figured that out (using custom webparts). Now I'm having another problem, I'm trying to use the 'WHERE' macro as you state above, but I don't know how to get to the fields from within the file. How would I access, for example, the Event Date? In the transformation I'm using <%# Eval('EventDate') %>, and that's fine, but can't figure out how to use it on here.

Comment: Good job answering your own comments before I could respond.  :)